# Jacobian for underdamped limit

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, brownian-motion, stochastic-processes

The underdamped langevin equation for harmonically bound particle is given as:

$m\overset{..}{x}+\zeta\overset{.}{x}+k\overset{.}{x}=\eta(t)$.

Suppose I know Probability distribution function of noise $\eta(t)$ which is $P(\eta_{1},\eta_{2}...\eta_{3})$. I want to get Probability distribution function of $x(t)$ which is $P(x_{1},x_{2}...x_{N})$. So I need to know jacobian matrix  $J[\frac{d\eta}{dx}]$. What would be the Jacobian for this transformation? Can you provide any reference for that?